# how two process communicate with each other

Tags: python

I'm very new with python.
I started implementing twp daemon processes that will send messages to each other.

right now i have just 2 daemons that are running.
I don't understand how to build something that they can communicate through..
I read that there are pipe, or queue ...
sill, could not understand how to build a pipe or a queue that the two ends will be the two processes..

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys

def daemon():
    p = multiprocessing.current_process()
    print 'Starting:', p.name, p.pid
    sys.stdout.flush()
    while (1):
        time.sleep(1)
    print 'Exiting :', p.name, p.pid
    sys.stdout.flush()

def machine_func():
    p = multiprocessing.current_process()
    print 'Starting:', p.name, p.pid
    sys.stdout.flush()
    while (1):
        time.sleep(1)
    print 'Exiting :', p.name, p.pid
    sys.stdout.flush() 


    cs = multiprocessing.Process(name='control_service',  target=control_service_func)
    cs.daemon = True

    m = multiprocessing.Process(name='machine', target=machine_func)
    m.daemon = True

    cs.start()
    m.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find very good examples here: [Communication Between Processes](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can communicate with daemons via text files like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from ast import literal_eval as literal
from random import random
import time

def clock():  # 24 hour clock formatted HH:MM:SS
    return str(time.ctime())[11:19]

def sub_a(): # writes dictionary that tallys +/- every second

    a = 0
    while 1:
        data = {'a': a}
        opened = 0
        while not opened:
            try:
                with open('a_test.txt', 'w+') as file:
                    file.write(str(data))
                    opened = 1
            except:
                print ('b_test.txt in use, try WRITE again...')
                pass
        a+=1
        time.sleep(random()*2)

def sub_b(): # writes dictionary that tallys +/- every 2 seconds

    b = 0
    while 1:
        data = {'b': b}
        opened = 0
        while not opened:
            try:
                with open('b_test.txt', 'w+') as file:
                    file.write(str(data))
                    opened = 1
            except:
                print ('b_test.txt in use, try WRITE again...')
                pass
        b += 1
        time.sleep(random()*4)

# clear communication lines
with open('a_test.txt', 'w+') as file:
    file.write('')
with open('b_test.txt', 'w+') as file:
    file.write('')

# begin daemons
sa = Process(target=sub_a)
sa.daemon = True
sb = Process(target=sub_b)
sb.daemon = True
sa.start()
sb.start()

begin = time.time()
m = 0
while 1:

    m += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    elapsed = int(time.time()-begin)

    #fetch data from deamons
    opened = 0
    while not opened:
        try:
            with open('a_test.txt', 'r') as f:
                a = literal(f.read())
                opened = 1
        except:
            print ('a_test.txt in use, try READ again...')
            pass

    opened = 0
    while not opened:
        try:
            with open('b_test.txt', 'r') as f:
                b = literal(f.read())
                opened = 1
        except:
            print ('READ b_test.txt in use, try READ again...')
            pass
    print(clock(), '========', elapsed, b['b'], a['a'])
```

in this manner you can make object (like a dict) into string, write() to file, then:

`ast.literal_eval`

to get it back out on the other side when you read()

`while not opened try`

method prevents race condition so daemons and main process have time needed to not clash while they open/process/close the file

`with open as file`

method ensures file is opened and closed efficiently

added bonus is you can open the text file in an editor to check its state in real time.